# Looking for something like uPnP for Angular web client

Tags: angularjs

I have an Angular web client on a dedicated hardware device. Every device has its own landing page.

On the landing page I now want to have the option to select **other devices** in the same network to log in (by calling its own web client).

What are good approaches to realize this? 
I think of a solution that is not IP based, somethink like uPnP. Every client should broadcast its own presence and all web client landing pages will show the same devices.